# Ethernet port on Linux machine not recognizing ethernet connection with embedded device

Tags: linux, ip, ethernet, ip-address, tcp

I have an atmel at91sam7x256 microcontroller that I would like to use for a TCP/IP communication. The very first step of my project is to be able to "ping" my board given its IP address. I have its IP address but the problem is that my Linux machine's ethernet port doesn't blink, therefore doesn't recognize, when I insert the ethernet cable connected to my board.

I am wondering what I might be able to do to fix this problem. This is the first time that I'm connecting my microcontroller to my machine so maybe there is some sort of configuration I must do prior to the connection.

For what it's worth, there is no problem with my machine's ethernet port because I've already connected other boards through ethernet to the same port.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Do the lights on both nics come on? Most modern ethernet ports can remap wires so you can use patch cable for all purposes (even those that previously required cross-patch cabling) but in your case, one of your devices may not have this capability. see if you can confirm that both nics support `auto MDI-X`. if not, you should try a piece of crosspatch cable.

Comment: I'm sorry but you said a lot of words I'm not so sure I understand! What do you mean by "nics"? And how can I check/confirm if both nics support `auto MDI-X`? For what it's worth, nothing lights up when I insert the ethernet cable to my machine from the device. Nor on the device side, nor on the machine side.

Comment: there are two kinds of Cat5 cable wiring: a standard patch cable, where each pin on one end comes out on the same pin on the other end, and cross-patch cable, where the read pins and the write pins are transposed. you used to have to use patch to connect from a computer to a switch, but if you wanted to connect two computers directly together without a device in the middle, you needed to use Cross-patch or Crossover cable. auto MDIX is a protocol that allows a nic to determine whether it should treat the cable as patch or crosspatch, and auto configures everything,so you can use the same cable

Comment: Well, I think my wire is a cross-patch cable. But regardless, I was able to link another board of mine with the same ethernet cable to the same machine. Does that say something about the new embedded device that I'm using?

Comment: you can use the linux utility `ethtool` to view information about the nic connection, including what kind of cable, whether its plugged in, linkspeed/duplex, and whether MDI-X is enabled. to run it on eth0, the command is `sudo ethtool eth0`

Comment: Oh, sorry, a NIC is the network card. it sounds like the network cards don't recognize that they are plugged into anything at all, so if they are powered on, it does sound like you have the wrong cable. you should be able to determine the kind of cable needed by consulting the embedded devices technical documentation and specs.

Comment: Hmm, so you think it might be a cable problem then? Is it that the type of cable might not be compatible with the device?

Comment: all I can say is consult your manufacturers documentation. we don't even know what kind of device this 'embedded device' is, so no way we can tell, but this is a common fix to a common problem (in fact if it is the problem, its the **only** fix.).

Comment: Ok, thank you. It's an atmel at91sam7x256 microcontroller like I mentioned in the post.

Comment: based on http://www.atmel.com/Images/6120s.pdf, the nic is 10/100BaseT, a rather old technology, so I would suspect you need a crosspatch cable. your nics will also have to both be set to 100Mbps Half Duplex. you can tell if you cable is patch by holding up both ends so the clips face away from you. is the orange wire the left-most one on both ends? if not, you have crosspatch.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! I have two types of ethernet cables. One with which the orange wire is the left-most on both ends of the cable. And one that isn't the cast (a crosspatch). But both cables don't cause the ethernet port to blink.

Comment: what does ethtool say on the linux side?

Comment: The command can't be found. And this is where I can't do anything about it because I can't install it because I don't have the adminstrative rights to do so. Is there anything else I could check to solve this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14379/discussion-between-john-smith-and-frank-thomas)

Comment: @FrankThomas I can use the `mii-tool` command, and I have the following for eth@: `negotiated 1000baseT-HD flow-control, link ok`.

Comment: it looks like your embedded device can't deal with that speed, but the lights should at least come on at link. I think you may have to contact atmel.

Comment: Oh, I see. That may cause a problem. Ok I'll check with atmel in that case. Is there a way to check for the ethernet settings for a Windows machine? Because the lights don't come on when I link the ethernet cable to my Windows machine either.

Comment: in your Network Adapter Properties, click Configure, and on the details tab, there should be info and options for setting linkspeed and duplex. you are shooting for 100baseT Half-Duplex.

Comment: I haven't found the options yet but thank you for helping. I hope I can connect to the Windows machine at least.